# What time stamp format is this?

Tags: timestamp, datetime-format

I've been trying to figure out what time stamp this is:

```
2021-01-06T11:00:00.459907-07:00
```

In particular the `.459907`, Ive been looking online but I haven't been able to find this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ISO 8601

The format is ISO 8601, the international standard. The long story is in the link at the bottom.

`.459907` is a fraction of second. Another way to describe it is that the time is 459 907 microseconds (millionths of a second) after 11 AM. The fixed letter `T` (for time, I suppose) before the time of day part is characteristic for ISO 8601.

Your string also includes a date, January 6, 2021, and an offset of minus 7 hours 00 minutes from UTC. Such an offset would be used at this time of year in America/Edmonton and America/Denver time zones (Mountain Time), for example. Offset -07:00 means the time is 7 hours behind UTC. So the corresponding UTC time would be 18:00:00.459907.

### Link

[Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 1):

In [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621142/10819573) Ole V.V. has already described the format of this date-time string. This answer adds a supplement to his answer.

Most of the languages have libraries to parse this kind of date-time String directly/indirectly e.g. in Java, you can parse this string into `OffsetDateTime` and thus retrieve individual information from it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-01-06T11:00:00.459907-07:00");
        long nanos = odt.getNano();
        System.out.println(odt + " has " + nanos + " nanoseconds");
        System.out.println(odt + " has " + odt.get(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND) + " microseconds");
        System.out.println(odt + " has " + odt.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND) + " milliseconds");
        System.out.println(nanos + " nanoseconds = " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros(nanos) + " microseconds");
        System.out.println(nanos + " nanoseconds = " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(nanos) + " milliseconds");
        System.out.println(odt + " has a zone-offset of " + odt.getOffset() + " from UTC");
        System.out.println("Month: " + odt.getMonth());
        System.out.println("Day of month: " + odt.getDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println("Weekday name: " + odt.getDayOfWeek());
        System.out.println("Week of the year: " + odt.get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR));
        System.out
                .println("In terms of UTC, " + odt + " can be represented as " + odt.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));

        OffsetDateTime odtWithNextCompleteSecond = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-01-06T11:00:01-07:00");
        System.out.println("After " + Duration.between(odt, odtWithNextCompleteSecond).toNanos()
                + " nanoseconds, this time will change to " + odtWithNextCompleteSecond);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-01-06T11:00:00.459907-07:00 has 459907000 nanoseconds
2021-01-06T11:00:00.459907-07:00 has 459907 microseconds
2021-01-06T11:00:00.459907-07:00 has 459 milliseconds
459907000 nanoseconds = 459907 microseconds
459907000 nanoseconds = 459 milliseconds
2021-01-06T11:00:00.459907-07:00 has a zone-offset of -07:00 from UTC
Month: JANUARY
Day of month: 6
Weekday name: WEDNESDAY
Week of the year: 1
In terms of UTC, 2021-01-06T11:00:00.459907-07:00 can be represented as 2021-01-06T18:00:00.459907Z
After 540093000 nanoseconds, this time will change to 2021-01-06T11:00:01-07:00
```

Anyone with working knowledge in Java can learn about the date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.